# iframe won't load in VF page

Tags: visualforce, iframe

Trying to iframe https://login.microsoftonline.com/ on a VF page.

However, I get the error: Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

> DENY: The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

You could instead open the URL in a new window rather than embedding it in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: There is no solution for this, the X-Frame-options is set to deny at the header level.

Microsoft may be doing this for security reasons, have a button to redirect your users to the login page of microsoft instead of iframing the login page.

Refer:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000182205&language=en_US